# WCF: how to restrict using some protocols?

Tags: wcf, protocols, restrict

WCF (winodws service hosting) service uses set of protocols and bindings: http, https, net.tcp, net.pipe. 
It uses config file settings.

I want to build demo version of the service. 
This demo will use only net.pipe protocol.
How I can restrict service to use only this one?
I can do changes in code , but how and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiceHost` owns collection of `ChannelDispatcher`s in `ChannelDispatchers` property. You can use `ChannelDispatcher.BindingName` to figure out name of binding used in your service.

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SomeService), baseAddress))
//configure service endpoints here
host.Open();

#if DEMO_MODE
foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in host.ChannelDispatchers)
{
   //binding name includes namespace. Example - http://tempuri.org/:NetNamedPipeBinding
   var bindingName = dispatcher.BindingName;
   if (!(bindingName.EndsWith("NetNamedPipeBinding") || bindingName.EndsWith("MetadataExchangeHttpBinding")))
     throw new ApplicationException("Only netNamedPipeBinding is supported in demo mode");
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you. WHy there is this condition?  || bindingName.EndsWith("MetadataExchangeHttpBinding"))

Comment: This is protocol that helps client applications development. It may be disabled in Live but very useful for develops. See details here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx